# How to Identify taggable friend uniquely using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to allow user to tag it's friend only once. however taggable_friends endpoint provides the temporary token id which does not persist on different api calls. I don't want Facebook id of the friend but any id that would be persistent whenever I fetch this endpoint.

Comment: Not possible. The id that you get back from taggable_friends changes for a reason

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up unanswered threads: As WizKid commented, it is not possible to identify a user with `taggable_friends`, because the token is only valid for a short time and it changes. You could only match the name of the user, there is no other way. It´s not 100% unique, of course - because the user could have 2 friends with the same name.